# Auto Updates (divs, spans, etc...)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I'd like to update the current value of an item if someone bids that item, the idea is that if one user bids, the others will receive the updated value automatacly.

How can i do this?

I thought about using async handlers or web methods, but not sure if is the right way.

EXAMPLE:

a user is bidding > bids 50€ and then the rest of the online users wich are in the current page of the project see the updated value. (the idea works more or less like facebook)

Comment: I would use a JavaScript timer to refresh a div or IFrame.

Comment: but if i use that i have to use a handler, to search in the database for changes, is it a good or only way to do it?

Comment: Try using signalr for this. See Microsoft documentation for usage examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SignalR](http://signalr.net/) allows realtime communication in .Net . Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time

Should allow you to build that sort of site. Have a look at this [example](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5) that shows a realtime chat application in MVC.

Principal is same. Combination of server side and js to update page. Customers who open the bid page are all registered with the server. When a bid is updated by one client it is sent to the server. The server validates and updates the new status of the bid process to all listening clients. A message is pushed and the client use JS to generally update the state of the page.

Answer (score 0):

In a client-server architecture, which you are using since you talk about web, I think you do not have many options here.

Using a database (or any other temporary storage, like session state or text file) is IMHO the only solution for the other clients to retrieve the value you want to share.

Kepping that in mind, I think the AJAX way is the better you can setup in your case, as suggested in the comments.

Have a look at [ASP.NET Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx) for server side, and [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for client side.